# PersistenceException when trying to add model after Globals.InitialData

Tags: playframework-2.0, h2, ebean

I'm using Play Framework 2.0 (Java), but after implementing a simple InitialData in Globals, I'm having some problem.
I'm using

I have 2 models:

- User(email as ID)
- SomeModel(Long id as ID)

And SomeModel has a field like:

```
@ManyToOne
  public User user;
```

So in the and there is a User has many SomeModels connected to it.

In my InitialData I was adding a user to test somethings: test@test.com.

So if I try to add a SomeModel to this test user, I have no problem, even if I try to add more then one.

When I added the SomeModel(lets call a TestModel) in the InitialData I thought that there was no problem, since everything was running in this TestModel. But just now, I saw that if I try to add a new SomeModel to the test user, I get this problem:

```
[PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_D ON PUBLIC.SOME_MODEL(ID)"; SQL statement:\n insert into some_model (id, name, description, user_email) values (?,?,?,?) [23505-158]]]
```

This is my InitialData file:

```
# Users

users:

    - !!models.User
        email:      test@test.com
        name:       Test test
        password:   test


# SomeModels
somemodels:

    - !!models.FuzzySystem
        id:       1
        name:       test
        description:   test
        user:       !!models.User
                            email: test@test.com
```

I'm lost in this =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I've just found out that the initialData shouldn't have the ID of SomeModel...

After removing the ID field everything worked just fine.

This is how my initialData file is:

```
# Users

users:

    - !!models.User
        email:      test@test.com
        name:       Test test
        password:   test


# SomeModels
somemodels:

    - !!models.FuzzySystem
        name:       test
        description:   test
        user:       !!models.User
                            email: test@test.com
```